# WORDPRESS - Unwanted HTML button background colour

Tags: html, wordpress, button, colors, background

I've made a sign up form with a submit button at the bottom. When deploying the code on the website, the button appears to have an unwanted grey background colour but only in a WordPress article. When tested outside WordPress, it appears fine. It seems WordPress changes it for some reason. Does anyone know why this might be?

[image]

Comment: Do you know what CSS is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with specificity. In CSS, if you have not given style to your button element, it will inherit the style of the parent element. For example: If your "article" class contains a style for button elements...

```
.myArticle button {
   background-color: #232323;
   color: black;
}
```

Your button in that article, if not given its own id/class will receive that style. To change this, simply give your button its own id/class.
For example:

```
#myButton {
     background-color: "color";
     color: "color";
}
```

Furthermore, looking at the image you linked to. The reason the two buttons are styled differently may be to do with the input type. In CSS you can also select inputs by attribute. Example:

```
.myArticle input[type=submit] {
     background-color: #232323;
     color: black;
}
```

Either way, I would just consider giving the button you're having trouble with, an ID. From there you should be able to manually style it.  ID's are one of the most specific selectors, no styles should overwrite that. Hopefully I've understood your question correctly, and this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. Massively helpful.